# Ubuntu 15.04/15.10 on MacBook Pro 11.1 locks up on sleep

Tags: 15.04, suspend, macbook-pro, 15.10

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 (now upgraded to 15.10) from a clean install on a MacBook Pro 11,1 alongside OS X. I followed instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/utopic). I have a problem that happens intermittently where, upon attempting to suspend, the OS locks up instead. The screen will be off, the keyboard light still on, and the machine will continue to do something (as evidenced by the very warm temperature of the laptop). However, it has become completely unrecoverable by the normal means: I'm unable to move to virtual console, turn on the screen, or perform any operation. I have to perform a hard reboot when this happens.

I've not been able to recover any information as to why it's doing this. I'm not sure what error, if any, is failing and causing this behavior. What can I do to debug this issue and figure out what is causing this failure to allow the laptop to suspend?

As a note, <strike>most of the time this does not happen</strike>, but it happens frequently enough for it to be a real hassle (at least once or twice a week, depending on how often I'm moving around with my laptop).

UPDATE 11/2/2015: At some point (even before my upgrade to 15.10) I noticed the behavior occurring much more frequently. It's to the point where I rarely chance letting my laptop suspend lest it lock itself up and force me to reboot it (after some period of time when I come back to find it locked up and toasty). Instead I just shut it down completely, which is pretty annoying. My ASUS doesn't have the same issue running the same OS and mostly the same software configuration so I'm guessing it's a hardware issue (something is not suspending properly and making it impossible to recover after a suspend as well).

Update 12/5/2015: As of today it's been at least a few weeks without the issue, even as I try to reproduce it. I believe it may have been fixed in some update of something. I'll leave the question open for a few more weeks to see if it happens again.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem in same OS (although with KDE Plasma) and same computer model. In my case the screen stays on, but only the (frozen) mouse pointer is visible over a black background; I notice something went wrong when the apple logo stays lighted after closing the lid.

Comment: In my case the screen is off so I can't tell if the mouse is responsive. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: The mouse isn't responsive in my case too. No, no solution found.

Comment: For me my macbook pro 11,2 gets just a blank screen on hibernate. This is a after a fresh install of 15.04

Comment: Anyone want me to bounty this question?

Comment: Also, i think it is caused by an incorrect installation: this happened one time to me and i figured it out i did the install incorrectly. The best alternative of sleep for me is turning the screen off.

Comment: @StarOS Just turning the screen off is not a viable option for me, I'd like to be able to utilize its suspend capability. But regarding the first part of your comment, could you explain more about the installation issue you had? And were you ever able to fix it? It sounds like it still doesn't work for you and you turn the screen off instead.

Comment: Actually, i had this issue before on a completely different PC (mine.) It seemed i installed Ubuntu on a way that worked but wasn't recommended and kinda buggy. I installed Ubuntu in a good and recommended way and boom, suspend works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not experienced the issue since the last update to this question. It must have been fixed in some update along the line.